# Hydenet r package: setnode() simulates wrong standard deviation for normal distribution

Tags: r, simulation, jags, bayesian-networks, rjags

In the r package hydenet I'm unable to simulate the standard deviations I inputted earlier using setnode(). hydenet exports to jags for simulations.

I load in libraries here and make a simple graph showing that node_a affects node_b

```
library(rjags)
library(HydeNet)

dag = HydeNetwork(~node_a
                  + node_b | node_a)
```

I give both nodes a standard deviation (node a is set to 100, node b is set to 0.25)

```
dag = setNode(dag, node_a, nodeType = "dnorm", mean = 10, sd = 100) #.1
dag = setNode(dag, node_b, nodeType = "dnorm", mean = "15 + 0.2*node_a", sd = 0.25)
```

I compile to Jags and simulate a data frame of 100000 below.

```
comp_dag = compileJagsModel(dag)
sim = HydeSim(comp_dag, variable.names = c("node_a", "node_b"), n.iter = 100000)
```

yet for some reason when I check the standard deviations for the nodes on the simulated data, the standard deviations are wrong. For some reason, simulated_sd=sqrt(1/input_sd). I also don't know why it follows this equation.

```
sd(sim$node_a)
#0.1000575
sd(sim$node_b)
#1.992311
```

when hydenet is fed the simulated data it estimates close to the original input of standard deviation, so weirdly that seems to work. This is unfortunate because I need to use both of these equations. Thus, it prevents me from just reversing the equation I derived before.

```
sim_dag = HydeNetwork(~node_a
                  + node_b | node_a, data = sim)
writeNetworkModel(sim_dag, pretty = T)
# model{
#    node_a ~ dnorm(9.99955, 100.00706)
#    node_b ~ dnorm(15.53815 + 0.1468 * node_a, 0.25169)
# }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, though I thought I'd leave my post up for anyone else who's confused. JAGs takes mean and precision not mean and standard deviations. Precision is 1/variance which also explains the equation I got between the input and output standard deviations.

Back calculating based on the equation I wrote `(simulated_sd = 1/sqrt(input_sd))` will work if you're simulating things from JAGS in R.